Microsoft Service Fabric Runtime for windows
I have installed Service Fabric Runtime for Windows 10.1.1951.9590
and Service Fabric SDK  7.1.1951. For some reason when I start service fabric local cluster and setup local cluster on Windows 1 Node I get "There were errors while setting up local cluster". Has anyone had same issues?
I tried to install another versions but still was not working.

windows 11 or windows 10? Which edition do you use ? (Pro, Home, ?)

It needs Net 4.5 installed.  Old Version : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services
